# How to set the "value" and "for" attribute using Object.assign

Tags: javascript, object, dom, attributes

How do I set the value of an element using `Object.assign()`? All other attributes seem to show up except `"value"`for an `<input>` and `"for"` for a `<label>`. Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function createForm () {

    // Form header >>>>
    const formHeaderText = document.createTextNode("Form");
    headerEl.appendChild(formHeaderText);
    container.appendChild(headerEl);

    // Form element >>>
    Object.assign(formEl, {
        name: "inputForm",
        id: "myForm"
    });
   container.appendChild(formEl);

    // Name Label >>>
    const nameLabelText = document.createTextNode("Name");
    labelElName.appendChild(nameLabelText);
    Object.assign(labelElName, {
        for: "iname",
    });
    formEl.appendChild(labelElName);

    // Name Input element >>>
    formEl.appendChild(inputElName);
    Object.assign(inputElName, {
        className: "inputs",
        id: "iname",
        name: "name",
        type: "text",
        placeholder: "Name",
        value: ""
    })
```

And what I get is:

```
<input class="inputs" id="iname" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
```

for the input and:

```
<label>Name</label>
```

for the label element.

Comment: It looks like you never define `labelElName`..?

Comment: Also where is `formEl` defined? What is it?

Comment: they are all saved in constants but I couldn't submit all the code... sorry

Comment: this is some of the code that didn't get submited: ```const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0]
const headerEl = document.createElement("h1");
const formEl = document.createElement("form");
const labelElName = document.createElement("label");
const labelElGender = document.createElement("label");
const labelElAge = document.createElement("label");
const inputElName = document.createElement("input");
const inputElGender = document.createElement("input");
const inputElAge = document.createElement("input");```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `for` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, you need to use `htmlFor` property on `label` element, like this:

```
Object.assign(labelElName, {htmlFor: "iname"});
```

or

```
labelElName.htmlFor = "iname";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for ```for``` attribute.

Comment: @Co.tibi for value on input, try to use `defaultValue` property.

Comment: @Co.tibi You're welcome. I would appreciate to mark the answer as accepted.